# EC2 instance stops responding after reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have created a private AMI from the image I had running from my other EC2 instance. When I create the instance using that private AMI, it boots up fine but when I restart the newly created instance, it stops responding. I can't even connect through SSH into it.

How can I see what is going wrong?

Comment: Is your EC2 instance connected to EBS for persistence? If it is not it can not be stopped and started. See Elastic Block Store section on this page: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Comment: Root device on the AWS console shows as EBS

Comment: Were you able to ping the server? Also, share the kind of error you get & the way your created your AMI? Confirm when you created your EBS AMI should have content in /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the system log, which will be helpful for knowing whats wrong.

[image]

Also make sure that the Security rules allows you to connect through ssh .